# TEX create a .sty file

Tags: packages, installing

I'm at my office and i have to install TEX package manually.
I have download the package `subfig` on CTAN, but their is no .sty file in the folder.

I convert in the past a file in sty passing by the cmd of window, but didn't remember how.

Does anyone have the solution ?

ps : sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why don't you just update your LaTeX installation? Hardly anyone need to manually install packages anymore. (if there is `.ins` run `latex` on it, if there is only a `.dtx` run `tex` on it)

Comment: I can't, because of office politics, i can't install anything from web whithout passing by software service. But i can do it manually

Comment: @Chris Presumably though you have a TeX system?

Comment: @ChristopheD. then ask your software service to update it (and ask them to install the full miktex so you are not missing other packages).

Comment: @daleif, it's not simple as that. Make more than 2month for them to act, and my training finish in 2 month so...

Comment: Nice environment to work in.....

Comment: @Community Please state why this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile the `.ins` in your favorite LaTeX editor

Comment: Did not know if it usefull but i use Sweave frome Rstudio to create my pdf.
I have created the .sty extension file withe miktex and put it in the package repository. 
But when i run the sweave file with the command `\usepackage{subfig}`  it require to install subfig.sty but didn't work...

Comment: You can find a complete guide here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows

Comment: Thank you Rud Faden, exactly what i want, i will edit my question with the exact procedure i used after !

Comment: I have no idea what the answer means.